# lessc with an absolute path in importing

Tags: less

I'm using `lessc` for less compilation. However, I cannot import an absolute LESS file, lessc always says that the imported file is not found.

For example,

A.less

```
@import /home/laptop/inc/inc.less
```

Comment: Where does A.less sit in relation to inc.less?

Comment: `A.less` is put anywhere in my computer, `/home/laptop/A.less` for instance

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  My only option otherwise is to wrap lessc in a pre-processing script that expands @import and paths from absolute paths stored in comments

Answer (score 0):

In my testing, absolute paths do not work. The solution is of course to make them relative paths. Thus when a less file is in my home directory (/Users/Gidgidonihah)

```
/Volumes/remove/less/mixins.less
```

becomes

```
../../Volumes/remove/less/mixins.less
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to put quotes around your file name, and end it with a semicolon.  Less is very strict about syntax.

```
@import "/home/laptop/inc/inc.less";
```

Comment: I get same result with above. lessc said that ' the file was not found'

Comment: Have you tried using the relative path to it?
    @import "../home/laptop/inc/inc.less";